# Fast lookup not working for Email Alert

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, email-alert, fast-lookup

I want to send Email Alert to Opportunity Owner when Account record is updated.Therefore I believe combination between Process builder and Flow  is a good idea.

Heads up, I am system admin and I don't have any issue on record access, I already test it before I create the email alert.

I created email alert using flow refer to this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_action_email_alert.htm&type=0) :

Initially I tried using Fast lookup -to retrieve Opportunity using AccountId that defined from process builder.
[image]

I tried assign Opportunity Id with SObject variable when it is not working, I tried also Sobject Collection Variable .When I tested it give me this error .This error really confusing because I should not have access issue.

> Error element send_email_to_Opportunity_Owner (FlowActionCall).
>   insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

I gave up using Fast look up, so I try to use Record lookup and it works without fuss.
Now because of this, I assume that Fast lookup will not work in Email Alert because Flow Email Alert element treats record id as text which not support in Fast lookup.Fast Lookup only has options SObject Variable or SObject Collection variable while Record Lookup offer more type.

> Record ID : Select a variable that contains the ID for the record that
>   you want the email to reference. If the email alert uses any merge
>   fields, this record is the starting point for those merge fields. This
>   field accepts single-value variables of any type. The value is treated
>   as text.

But I don't want to assume.So is that true Email alert won't work with Fast Lookup.Has anyone try and success? 
[image]

Comment: Fast Lookup will work for Email alert Global action @unidha

Comment: After Fast Lookup you have to add decision element to check for the condition  to send Email alert

Comment: Do you mean Fast Look up will work if add decision while Record Lookup no need decision? What I understand decision required if you want different outcome .

Comment: yes we need Decision Element for Fast Lookup Element box

Comment: where you get struck,please post i will help you  in flow

Answer (score 0):

Fast Lookup will work for the Email Alert Global Action

[image]

The above structured Flow i have worked to send Email to check the condition for sending Email to bulk of Records

Comment: What is Email Alert Global Action, I am lost here?

Comment: @unidha i have send above sample diagramatic flow structure,Last Account.checking Email alert Global action

Comment: Still it does not answer my question, what is Email Alert Global Action? Also may I know what type of Fast lookup variable that you use and is your flow is called from Process Builder?

Comment: yes  my flow is called from Process Builder